# How do I start a Thread but keep it alive for a certain time?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.scanner

I don't really want to start a thread then put it to sleep, such as:

```
Thread.start();
Thread.sleep(3000);  //*Example*
```

Instead, I want to this something like this (And I apologize for this amateur illustration):

```
Thread.start(3000) //*thread will be given a certain amount of time to execute* 

 //*After 3000 milliseconds, the thread stops and or sleeps*
```

I'm doing this because I'm making a program/ mini-game that times user input for a certain time. Basically, the user has 5 seconds to input a certain character/number/letter and after that time, the input stream is cut off. Kind of like:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = kb.nextInt();
kb.close()    //*Closes kb and input stream in turn*
```

Comment: use a [java.util.timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) .. `A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.`

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. That the task happens to be done by a thread is irrelevant. Your question is "how can I time out a task if it takes too long". You don't reach out into a thread from the inside to make it do what it's supposed to do, you code it to do what it's supposed to do in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and [`scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable, long, long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). You can cancel that if the user completes whatever task before the delay expires. If the delay runs out then the user failed whatever task.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample.

```
    final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        volatile boolean isDone = false;
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isDone = true;
                }
            }, 5000);

            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (!isDone) {
                int num = 0;
                num = kb.nextInt();
                result.add(num);
            }
            kb.close();
        }

    };
    thread.start();
    thread.join();

    for (Integer i : result) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
```